# Inserir Parenteses entre uma sigla no campo input

Tags: javascript, substring

Boa tarde pessoal, Estou com um probleminha em inserir parentêses entre siglas de um campo que eu criei. Segue meu código:

```
function maiusculo(){
    var quadro = document.getElementById("quadro").value;
    quadro = quadro.toUpperCase();
    quadrocorrige= "("+ quadro +")";
    document.getElementById("quadro").value = quadrocorrige;
}
```

O usuário, poderá digitar o Parenteses, mas só pode sair apenas um par, ou seja, se o usuário digitar a sigla *RJ*, o input corrige para ***(RJ)***! Mas se o usuário digita *(RJ)*, o javascript tá colocando ***((RJ))***.

Eu necessito que as siglas fiquem em maiúsculo e que estejam entre parentêses.

Comment: Não entendi seu problema. Você quer que isso seja como uma máscara, ou melhor, execute a cada vez que o usuário pressionar uma tecla?

Comment: @WeslleyCXSardinha, como uma máscara

Comment: Você está utilizando JQuery?

Comment: Não @WeslleyCXSardinha

Answer (score 0):

Para que uma função seja executada a cada tecla digitada, usamos o evento `oninput`:

```
document.getElementById("quadro").oninput = function(){

    var value = this.value;

    var arr = value.split(' ');

    if(arr[0] && arr.length > 1){
        arr[0] = '(' + arr[0].replace(/\(|\)/g, '').toUpperCase() + ')';
    }

    this.value = arr.join(' ');

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Fiz alguns ajustes aqui, e funcionou se caso o usuário inserir os parenteses a função não insere mais. veja se te ajuda qualquer coisa poste um comentário que te ajudo.

```js
function maiusculo(){
    var quadro = document.getElementById("quadro");
    quadro = quadro.value.toUpperCase();
    
    if(quadro.charAt(0) !== "(" && quadro.charAt(quadro.length -1) !== ")" ){
        quadro = "(" + quadro +")";
    }
    
    
    var quadro = document.getElementById("quadro").value = quadro
    document.getElementById("a").innerHTML = quadro;
    
}
```

```html
<input id="quadro">
<button onclick="maiusculo()">ver valor</button>
<h1 id="a"></h1>
```

Answer (score 0):

Só mais uma outra maneira que pode de ser feita:

```js
var quadro = document.getElementById("quadro");

function maiusculo() {
  var valor = quadro.value;
  quadrocorrige = "(" + valor + ")";
  document.getElementById("quadro").value = quadrocorrige.toUpperCase();
}

quadro.onkeyup = function() {
  var valor = quadro.value;
  var rgex = /[(|)]/;  // regex que impede o uso dos () pelo usuário
  
  if(valor.length == 2) {
    maiusculo();
  } else if(valor.length == 3 ) {
    quadro.value = ''
  } else if(valor.match(rgex)) {
    quadro.value = '';
  }
}
```

```html
<input id="quadro">
```

Answer (score -1):

Tenta colocar um replace para remover os `(` `)`

```js
function maiusculo(){
    var quadro = document.getElementById("quadro").value;
    quadro = quadro.toUpperCase();
    quadrocorrige= "("+ quadro.replace("(", "").replace(")", "") +")";
    document.getElementById("quadro").value = quadrocorrige;
}
```

```html
<input id="quadro">
<button onclick="maiusculo()">ver valor</button>
```